# Return array of multiple different objects?

Tags: java, coding-style, clean-code

I have code along the following lines:

```
public void processInput() {
    List<String> input = readInput();
    final Object[] returnObj = createInternalStructureFrom(input);
    final Dictionary dictionary = (Dictionary) returnObj[0];
    final List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>) returnObj[1];
    final List<String> invalidInput = (List<String>) returnObj[2];

    // some more code that processes the created objects
}

private Object[] createInternalStructureFrom(final List<String> input) {

    // here is some code that creates objects along the lines of

    // Dictionary dictionary = createDictionaryFrom(input);
    // List<Order> orderList = createOrderListFrom(input);
    // List<String> invalidInput = getInvalidInputFrom(input);

    // but actually these methods can not be seperated
    // and all objects are created simultaniously when the input is parsed

    final Object[] returnObj = new Object[3];
    returnObj[0] = dictionary;
    returnObj[1] = orderList;
    returnObj[2] = invalidInput;
    return returnObj;
}
```

So the  'createInternalStructureFrom' method returns an array of objects of different kinds which are then cast to the corresponding type in the caller method.

Is this considered good practice in terms of writing clean code? What would be the alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

> Is this considered good practice in terms of writing clean code?

Hell, no! It's horrible.

> What would be the alternatives?

Create a class which has those things as fields and return an instance of that class. Furthermore, that class can have methods which use the data to do useful things. That's what OOP means: put the logic where the data is instead of ferrying around the data between procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I don't need those values together in any other place of the program? Would you still prefer to create a class?

Comment: @AndreasBraun: that or make them into fields of this class and maybe move stuff that has nothing to do with those fields somewhere else. Which is actually the same thing. createInternalStructureFrom() could be the constructor of the class. The point is that the data should live with the code that works on it.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is bad practice. The proper solution is to create a class of your own with members of the appropriate types.

There are many reasons why this is better:

- There is no possibility of forgotten, wrong or subtly wrong typecasts. Instead of slow, risky manual casts you get automatic, efficient storage verified by the compiler.
- The members can have descriptive names instead of hard-to-remember positions in the nondescript Arrays.
- You can pass around multiple values in one object if you ever need them together in another place of your program (and experience teaches that you often will).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I don't need those values together in any other place of the program? Would you still prefer to create a class?

Comment: @AndreasBraun Yes, creating a class is still better for the reasons of type-safety and mnemonic names. (If Java allowed you to do multiple returns like Python, e.g. `(dict, list, errors) = parseInput()`, then you could skip defining an explicit class, but it doesn't, so you should go with the special-purpose class.)